# Is there a proper place to let people know about software related Kickstarter projects

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am currently backing an open source JavaScript presentation framework that I use and believe is one of the best available.  I am leaving out the name here on purpose as I don't know what proper etiquette or the rules are about this.  I am not the creator, author, nor am I associated with this project in any way other than I am currently using the framework.  I would really like to see the project get funded as it will accelerate development of this project to even better functionality and will enable the group behind the framework to create a series of learning videos.

Is there a proper way to point the vast StackOverflow community to this project as I believe there would be a very large group of developers who would be interested and could use this open source software.

Comment: Buy an advertisement.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would a Javascript framework funded by kickstarter not go the way of so many other presentation frameworks, and become "pay to play"?

Comment: For those of us who are genuinely curious, consider putting the name of the framework in your Stack Overflow profile's "About Me" box (the rules are a bit more relaxed there).

Comment: Grinch, see the top voted open source project on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014/213961#213961  at least at the time I wrote this comment.  I sent the information in the answer below to the creator of the JavaScript Framework and he took the necessary steps to get it advertised in a sidebar.  As far as pay to play, since I am simply a user of the framework I can only say that it has been free up to this point and my understanding is that the model is to make money by consulting, training, videos, etc. but framework will remain free to use.

Comment: I also added information to my profile's "About Me" section that was previously empty. In that section I mention the JavaScript Presentation Framework that is the subject of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to promote it via Open Source Advertising that gets displayed in the sidebar on the main site:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/

Comment: Just remember, the Open Source Advertising is advertising for the purposes of getting developers to help contribute, not for advertising it for their use.  It might still be applicable for this question, but I wanted to make sure the purpose of that project was mentioned.